# AttributeError from PDF Export from ArcMap Bookmark Loop

Tags: arcpy, export, pdf, attributeerror

```
import arcpy, os, datetime

folderPath = r"C:\path"
dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

basename = "Flows"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\path\file.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
#loops through bookmarked locations and executes a PDF export
for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, "",data_frame=df):
    #going through text elements to find the map title and set it to the bookmark name
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "documentTitle"):
        elm.text = str(bkmk.name) + " - Flows"
        #set extent to bookmark extent before pdf export
        df.extent = bkmk.extent


    print basename + "_" + bkmk.name + " is exporting to PDF"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, basename + "_" + bkmk.name + "_" + dateTimeStamp)
    print basename + "_" + bkmk.name + " successfully exported to PDF"
    print "Done exporting this folder to PDF - " +folderPath


#cleanup
del mxd
```

I'm receiving the following error after attempting to loop through about 10 bookmarks worth of PDF exports. The odd thing is, if I do 3-4 bookmarks at a time, it will export successfully but not if I do the full set of 10.

> AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in executing ExportToPDF

Comment: Can every PDF be exported if done one at a time?  If so, then it would appear that you may be running out of resources.  You could try making your list of bookmarks first, then deleting that MapDocument object, then *within your loop* of the bookmarks recreate your MapDocument object and delete it.

Comment: I've found it helpful to set a time.sleep function in the loop when exporting so that ArcMap has time to refresh in between switching bookmarks. Or after the export too. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm

Comment: @dslamb how much time to you generally give between exports or between switching bookmarks?

Comment: @PolyGeo I ended up deleting the completed bookmarks then rerunning the script and it would work fine. Seems like it is running out of resources. I may try to do the time sleep first as what you've suggested will require quite a bit of tinkering for me. (new to arcpy and python)

Answer (score 0):

If every PDF can be exported when done one at a time, then it would appear that you may be running out of resources.

You could try making your list of bookmarks first, then deleting that MapDocument object, then *within your loop* of the bookmarks recreate your MapDocument object and delete it.

The kind of untested refactoring of your code that I think may work is:

```
import arcpy, os, datetime

folderPath = r"C:\path"
dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

basename = "Flows"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\path\file.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
bkmks = arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, "",data_frame=df)
del mxd

#loops through bookmarked locations and executes a PDF export
for bkmk in bkmks:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\path\file.mxd")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    #going through text elements to find the map title and set it to the bookmark name
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "documentTitle"):
        elm.text = str(bkmk.name) + " - Flows"
        #set extent to bookmark extent before pdf export
        df.extent = bkmk.extent

    print basename + "_" + bkmk.name + " is exporting to PDF"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, basename + "_" + bkmk.name + "_" + dateTimeStamp)
    print basename + "_" + bkmk.name + " successfully exported to PDF"
    print "Done exporting this folder to PDF - " +folderPath
    #cleanup
    del mxd
```